# How can I get a user's associated Apple ID from the command line?

Tags: terminal, icloud, command-line, apple-id, bash

I'd like to be able to retrieve the current user's associated Apple ID from a shell script. My first guess was to do so using `dscl` which I can get using my own user. But I'm not sure how reliable/consistent this method would be generally for any user.

`dscl . readpl /Users/[username] dsAttrTypeNative:LinkedIdentity appleid.apple.com:linked\ identities:0:full\ name`

Are there any alternative ways to do this? Maybe reading a plist somewhere using `defaults read`?

Comment: ID associated with what? It's quite possible to have more than one ID, used for different purposes.

Answer (score 2):

AppleIDs aren't specifically 'associated' with any given local user account - if there is an AppleID signed in on the Mac you might try using mas:

https://github.com/argon/mas

Specifically the command `mas account` should show you the currently logged-in AppleID.

Comment: That's actually not entirely true. Any user that has enabled iCloud services with their account has definitely created an association between their Apple ID and user account. There is also a specific iCloud feature that allows a user's password to be reset after first authenticating with their Apple ID. This would not be possible without some kind of association.

Comment: All true, but that's an optional step that a local user may not have taken, which is what I was referring to.

Comment: Ah I gotcha, makes sense.