# How can i get my apple id by terminal in MacBook?

Tags: terminal, apple-id

How can i get my apple id via terminal <kbd>command</kbd>?

I tested `dscl` command in my terminal with the following parameters?

1. > ```
   > dscl . -list /Users AppleID
   > ```
2. > ```
   > dscl . -list /Users UniqueID
   > ```

But i didn't get anything with these commands. I need to get my apple id via command line.

Any suggestion?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256013/how-can-i-get-a-users-associated-apple-id-from-the-command-line

Comment: I support it depends in which section of the OS or app you enter your AppleID - there are quite a few places it can be used and you don’t have to use the same ID across all the locations…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information about the currently logged in Apple ID can be retrieved with the following command: `defaults read MobileMeAccounts Accounts`
Alternatively, you can take a look at the tool [mas-cli](https://github.com/mas-cli/mas). With the command `mas account` you can also query the Apple ID.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to make `mas-cli` and have a stand-alone (portable) executable. Is that possible?

Comment: Upvote bacause of `defaults read MobileMeAccounts Accounts` command

Comment: Thanks... i get it. but i have to parse the apple id from command output

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to get my apple id. There's a file named my apple id in the following path:

```sh
ls ~/Library/Application\ Support/iCloud/Accounts/ | grep @
```

This is the output:

```
examplAccount@gmail.com
```

There's two files in the <kbd>../Account</kbd> directory and i have to filter them and separate them with `@` sign, because an apple id has `@` sign within itself.

Answer (score 3):

I improved **[@rollcoaster](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420709/how-can-i-get-my-apple-id-by-terminal-in-macbook/420711#420711)** answer as bellow :

```
user$ defaults read MobileMeAccounts Accounts | grep AccountID | cut -d \" -f2
```

The output of `defaults read MobileMeAccounts Accounts` statement is a *json*, so i applied `grep` command on this *json* to get `AccountID` field. Finally i extracted the content of quoted string from the output.

Comment: You can use PlistBuddy  under `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` with a simple XPath-like query syntax [for that](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363102/is-it-possible-to-query-the-current-users-apple-id-from-the-command-line/363106#363106): `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :Accounts:0:AccountID" ~/Library/Preferences/MobileMeAccounts.plist
`